# I am wondering about how to kill the processes

Tags: c, linux, fork

I create child using the fork and I try to kill the generated child every 3 seconds. I also try to kill my parents using "raise or kill".
I don't know how to do to kill parent processor.
When I run my code except kill parent, unlike my expectations, so many child kill come out.

that's the code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>    

int main()
{

   int ch[3];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       ch[i] = fork();
       if (ch[i] == 0){
             printf("child[%d]=%d\n",i,getpid());
             exit(0); }        
   }

   for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
       sleep(3);
       kill(ch[i],SIGKILL);
       printf("Killch[%d]=%d\n",i,ch[i]); 
   }

      /* KILL or raise() parent kill */

}
```

How can I correct this code?

Comment: Don't the child processes die by themself by calling `exit(0)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this thing?  It is strange and there is probably a better way to go about your true goal.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` for the `fork()` and `getpid() and `sleep() functions.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   Consider the closing brace '}' to be a separate statement

Comment: there are 3 return conditions from the function: `fork()`.  The posted code does not handle the condition when the call to `fork()` fails, thereby returning -1

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 3.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult o understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: given the posted code, most likely, all the child processes have already exited before the calls to `kill()` are ever executed

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` is not correct solution to collect child status, use `wait() or waitpid()` in parent.

when parent is in sleep

```
for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
       sleep(3);
       kill(ch[i],SIGKILL);
       printf("Killch[%d]=%d\n",i,ch[i]); 
   }
```

in your code `child` is not waiting for parent to kill  ? child is killed by itself by `exit(0)` statement.

You`(child)` need to send it's `exit status` to parent and parent's need to `collect` the child's status using `wait() or waitpid()` and then kill ?

If you want to observe that whether parent is killing child or not, use delay in child and observe.

"I try to kill the generated child " I ? assuming parent,Here is my code

```
int a[3];
int temp[3]; //to set flag=1 , when child completes instruction and become zombie
//collect status in wait() in parent, so no need to further process in my_isr
void my_isr(int n) //if child has not completed instruction, i.e not removed by wait() in parent
{ //then remove it using my_isr
        printf("in isr..\n");
        static int i;
        for(;i<3;i++)
                if((temp[i]!=1) )//if first child "not turned into zombie and removed by parent" then kill it
                {
                        printf("child %d killed \n",i+1);
                        kill(a[i],SIGKILL);
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("zombie child %d has been terminated normally \n",i+1);
                }
}
int main()
{
        if( (a[0]=fork()) == 0)
        {
                int r;
                srand(getpid());
                r=rand()%10+1;
                printf("child %d is going for sleep of %d sec\n",getpid(),r);
                sleep(r);
                exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
                if( (a[1]=fork()) == 0)
                {
                        int r;
                        srand(getpid());
                        r=rand()%10+1;
                        printf("child %d is going for sleep of  %d sec\n",getpid(),r);
                        sleep(r);
                        exit(2);
                }
                else
                {
                        if( (a[3]=fork()) == 0)
                        {
                                int r;
                                srand(getpid());
                                r=rand()%10+1;
                                printf("in child %d is going for sleep of  %d sec\n",getpid(),r);
                                sleep(r);
                                exit(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                int s;
                                printf("in parent : %d \n",getpid());
                                signal(SIGALRM,my_isr);
                                //setting timer to tell child's that you need to completes within this duration
                                alarm(5);
                                while(wait(&s) != -1)//when there is no child left , wait returns  -1
                                {
                                        if( s>>8 == 1 )
                                                temp[0]=1; //set the flag when exit status is received
                                        else if( s>>8 == 2)
                                                temp[1]=1; //set the flag when child completed work before

                                        else if( s>>8 ==3)
                                                temp[2]=1; //set the flags when zombies are removed
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I hope it help's you.